# 2d array to fputcsv not working

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, fputcsv

My array looks like this;

```
Array
(
 [0] => January
 [1] => 2015-01-30
 [2] => 2015-01-15
 [3] => February
 [4] => 2015-02-27
 [5] => 2015-02-18
 [6] => March
 [7] => 2015-03-31
 [8] => 2015-03-18
)
```

How can I output it to a csv in three columns? One for the Month name, and the other two for the two dates that follow.

At the moment my code looks like this;

```
$header = array("Month","Date One","Date Two");

$fp = fopen($filename, "w");
fputcsv ($fp, $header, "\t");
foreach($payments_array as $row){
     fputcsv($fp, array($row), "\t");
}
fclose($fp);
```

The headers go in fine, but I don't know how to get three columns on the data. At the moment at array goes in to the csv all in one column.

I thought `array_chuck()` might help - but I couldn't work it out.

Comment: Is it possible for you to make your array() to a multidimensional array ? Like array("January" => array("2015-01-30", "2015-01-15"))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

Here I just change the structure from:

```
Array
(
    [0] => January
    [1] => 2015-01-30
    [2] => 2015-01-15
    [3] => February
    [4] => 2015-02-27
    [5] => 2015-02-18
    [6] => March
    [7] => 2015-03-31
    [8] => 2015-03-18
)
```

to:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => January
            [1] => February
            [2] => March
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2015-01-30
            [1] => 2015-02-27
            [2] => 2015-03-31
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2015-01-15
            [1] => 2015-02-18
            [2] => 2015-03-18
        )

)
```

I do this with splitting the array into chunks of 3 with [`array_chunk()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php). After this I just go through the header array and take each [`array_column()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) and put it in the `$data` array. After this you can simply loop through the array as you did and write each line in your `.csv` file.

```
<?php

    $arr = array_chunk($arr, 3);

    foreach($arr[0] as $k => $v)
        $data[] = array_column($arr, $k);


    $fp = fopen($filename, "w");
    foreach($data as $row){
         fputcsv($fp, $row, "\t");
    }
    fclose($fp);

?>
```

output:

```
January February    March
2015-01-30  2015-02-27  2015-03-31
2015-01-15  2015-02-18  2015-03-18
```

**EDIT:**

I think I missed something; So this should be what you want:

```
<?php

    $data = array_chunk($arr, 3);
    $header = array("Month","Date One","Date Two");

    $fp = fopen($filename, "w");
    fputcsv($fp, $header, "\t");
    foreach($data as $row){
        fputcsv($fp, $row, "\t");
    }
    fclose($fp);

?>
```

output:

```
Month   "Date One"  "Date Two"
January 2015-01-30  2015-01-15
February    2015-02-27  2015-02-18
March   2015-03-31  2015-03-18
```

Comment: Closer than I've managed! Thanks. But your solution creates 12 columns and 3 rows. I wanted 3 columns on 12 rows.

Comment: @mike3875 What, how? Your array only has 9 elements! So it's just creates 3 rows with 3 columns each. What array do you really use and what output would you expect?

Comment: @mike3875 I think I see it now what you mean, updated my answer

Comment: @mike3875 So was my edit the solution or another answer? Or where are we? If nothing helped you please make sure you show us your **real** array and your expected output

Comment: yeah sorry about that. I meant 9. Your updated answer got it correct!

Answer (score 0):

Clean up the data...  I see Rizier123's answer now... probably cleaner.  Anyway crux of what everyone is saying, get the array the way you want it, then worry about the fputcsv.

```
$payments_array = [
 'January',
 '2015-01-30',
 '2015-01-15',
 'February',
 '2015-02-27',
 '2015-02-18',
 'March',
 '2015-03-31',
 '2015-03-18'];

$better_payments_array = [];
for ($i=0; $i<count($payments_array); $i++) {   
    $better_payments_array[] = [$payments_array[$i], $payments_array[$i+1],     $payments_array[$i+2]]; 
    $i=$i+2;
}

var_dump($better_payments_array);

array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(7) "January"
    [1]=>
    string(10) "2015-01-30"
    [2]=>
    string(10) "2015-01-15"
  }
  [1]=> ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$array=array( 'January','2015-01-30','2015-01-15','February','2015-02-27','2015-02-18','March','2015-03-31','2015-03-18');

$header = array("Month","Date One","Date Two");
$chunks=array_chunk($array,3);
$fp = fopen('test.csv', "w");
fputcsv ($fp, $header, "\t");
for($i=0;$i<count($chunks);$i++) {


    fputcsv($fp, $chunks[$i], ',');


}
fclose($fp);
```

`array_chunk`, as you've mentioned, is used, and works fine in this example.